# Why direction doesn't work correctly?

Tags: html, css, data-structures, direction

I have two rows like these:

```css
td{direction: rtl;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>این یک متن تست است – <span>username</span> – <span>timestamp</span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>It is a test – <span>username</span> – <span>timestamp</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`این یک متن تست است` and `It is a test` are exactly the same thing and I want an identical position for both of them, but I don't know their position will be change after executing ..! How can I fix it?

I want this structure:

```css
tr{direction: rtl;}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
      <td>این یک متن تست است – <span>username</span> – <span>timestamp</span></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>It is a test س– <span>username</span> – <span>timestamp</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**Note:** I don't want to add any new HTML tag. I want to solve it using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to say is that they're not aligned together. This is happening because persian is a RTL language while English is a LTR language as obvious so you're trying to contradict them.

Try using the  tag on the table. If you don't like the result, then align the persian to the right and align the english to the left. Hope I helped. Good luck.

Comment: emm, this isn't what I need, but ok thansk, +1

Comment: I don't want the +1, I wanna help but you're not explaining the problem thoroughly. Could you show by example?

Comment: I gave you +1 because you mentioned to two great points ..! not jute because ..! btw my question is containing an example ..!

Answer (score 0):

As Golden Eagle said, its a language issue...

Just try this, please:

```
td{direction: rtl; text-align: left;}
```

Comment: I did no get your ploblem, then... Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I want this pattern both for English and Persian context: `<span>timestamp</span> - <span>username</span> - text`